# Bash variables in sed including an end of line condition

Tags: shell, sed

I have a bash variable replacement in sed, where some information at the end of line of the 3rd line for example should also be matched.

```
a=3 #line no
b=tap #pattern
c=9 #replacement data
sed "${a}s/${b}$/${c}/g"
```

The dollar to match the end of line doesn't seem to work, the one here ${b}**$**. 
***The script works without the dollar***

For example, in a file :

```
3, 7, 9
1, 3, 5
11, 23, tap
```

which should become 11, 23, **9**, I wanted the $ to identify tap as the last object. Now, tap can be a number too, so don't specialize it to a text.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of it not seeming to work? afaik a double-quoted `$` on its own shouldn't be subject to expansion (although you could try `\$` if there's doubt)

Comment: in a file, have three fields: 
3, 4, 5
9, 8, 7
1, 3, tap

should become 6, 7, 9

Comment: Well aside from the `g` modifier not really making sense when the pattern is anchored, I don't see what the issue is here?

Comment: What result is giving your above `sed` command? maybe you forgot to tell `sed` the input file it should run that replacement in?

Comment: I've cat'ted the file before and after replacement. Nothing happens !
Do you think it has anything to do with file format ? It's a simple csv file

Comment: well yes, cat before, sed -i and cat after.

Comment: Your command needs `sed -i` or else it will just send the result to standard output instead of actually changing the file

Comment: Are there any whitespace characters (tab, space, etc) after `tap`? They may be invisible but they'll still stop `tap$` from matching.  Also, where did this file come from? is it from a windows machine (which uses CR+LF as end-of-line marker, instead of just LF)....the extra CR is also invisible whitespace and would also prevent `tap$` from matching.   Running `cat -A filename` (or `cat -vET filename` if not using GNU `cat`) would reveal if either of these are the case.